# Issue with Security for Cusom API Connector for Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

We are trying to create a Custom API connector for our API so that it can be used within the Logic App. Our API is OAuth 2.0 protected (OKTA is the authentication provider) and we use client credential grant for generating the token for accessing the API.

The issue is while going into the security tab and selecting OAuth 2.0 and Generic OAuth, there is no option to select the grant type and the fields - Authorization URL and Refresh URL are mandatory. As you know client credential grant will not have authorization URL and Refresh URL. Therefore how can we configure Client Credential Grant?

Also, our API is exposed over Azure API Management and the API in APIM is protected with Subscription Key and the back-end API is protected with OAuth 2.0. Therefore, how can we create a custom API Connector for this API?